# Pixely Rendering of latex using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

In various cases whenever I use latex in matplotlib, I am getting a very pixely appearance when rendering the figure to an image.  When I view the figure in interactive mode it looks fine.  For example, I'm setting the yaxis label with:

'Emissions Flux '+r'($\mathregular{(\mu g/m^2 s)}$'

I'm also setting the twin y axis to a log scale and the eponents are presumably latex as well.  Non latex text is crisp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as far I understand the problem your images are too pixelated. Often this is the result of saving an image using a bitmap format. To receive better images one should export them to vector-graphs, like for example `pdf`.

To export images as vector-graphs your save statement should be something like:

```
myfig.savefig('myfig.pdf', format='pdf')
```

A clear explanation about bitmaps and vector graphs: [http://www.prepressure.com](http://www.prepressure.com/library/file-formats/bitmap-versus-vector),
an important source of information concerning matlibplot: [http://matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html)